# Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 4 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 4 found.

```
body: TabBarView(
        Text ("CAMERA "),
        Text("CHATS"),
        Text("STATUS"),
        Text("CALLS"),
        children: [],
      ),
```

Comment: Your question is vague, but even so, the error is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
body: TabBarView(children:
 [
  Text ("CAMERA "),
  Text("CHATS"),
  Text("STATUS"),
  Text("CALLS"),
 ]       
),
```

the content of tabBar must be inside children list.